# Xamarin.ios UiPageViewController Constraints changes, when the page appears again after navigating to different page

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uipageviewcontroller

I have a view controller in xamarin.ios which contains a UIPageViewController. The issue is that when I navigate to any other page and comeback to the page that has UIPageViewController, the side constraints are totally ignored.

[image: This is the correct design before I navigate to other page:]

[image: This is what happens after I navigate to other page and come back to see this]

Solution in xamarin.ios is preferable

Comment: How and where did you set the constraints? Could you show more detail code ?

Comment: I created a separate viewcontroller for the pageviewcontroller  and the constraints are set in storyboard. It all works good when the page appears for the first time